# Given $x^2+y^2=n$ and $2^k\| n$, prove that $2^{k/2}\| \gcd(x,y)$ if $k$ is even, and $2^{(k-1)/2}\| \gcd(x,y)$ if $k$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

**Question**: Given three integers $x,y,n$ such that $x^2+y^2=n$ and $2^k\| n$, prove that $2^{k/2}\| \gcd(x,y)$ if $k$ is even, and $2^{(k-1)/2}\| \gcd(x,y)$ if $k$ is odd.

*Could anybody please give me a hint?*

Note: $a^b\| n$ means that $a^b\mid n$ but $a^{b+1}\not\mid n$

Comment: Try induction. If $4 | n$ then $x, y$ must be even, and substituting $x = 2x', y=2y', n= 4n'$ gives you $x'^2 + y'^2 = n'$.

Comment: Have you studied divisibility in the ring of Gaussian integers? This follows immediately from the fact that $1+i$ is the only prime above $2$ andthat the ring is a UFD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $2^d\|\gcd(x,y)$, write $x=2^da$, $y=2^db$, where at least one of $a,b$ is odd.
Then 
$$ x^2+y^2=2^{2d}(a^2+b^2)$$
and $a^2+b^2$ is either odd (if $a\not\equiv b\pmod 2$), or is $\equiv 2\pmod 8$ (if both $a$ and $b$ are odd). Hence either $2^{2d}\|n$ or $2^{2d+1}\|n$.